# Displaying information from an array list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of driver names, that is displayed on my page and I want to get more information about the driver when I click on the name. I am struggling with running a function.
Here's what my html looks like:

```
<main>
<nav id="list">

</nav>
<section id="profile">

</section>
```

That's my list:

```
const drivers = [{
  name: "data",
  age: "data1",
  nationality: "data2"
}]
```

And that's the function I am trying to run:

```
function driverProfile(drivers) {
  const article = document.createElement('article');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  const h2 = document.createElement('h2');

  h2.textContent = drivers[driver_id].nationality;
  span.textContent = drivers[driver_id].age;
  article.textContent = drivers[driver_id].name;
 }

 myProfile = driverProfile(drivers)
 profile.appendChild(myProfile)
```

I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` pointing to `profile.appendChild(myProfile)`

My list function:

```
drivers.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, index) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = `?driver=${index}`;
  a.textContent = driver.name;
  list.appendChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better practice to group elements. First append elements in div then append new divs to `section`:

```
function driverProfile(drivers) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const article = document.createElement('article');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  const h2 = document.createElement('h2');

  h2.textContent = drivers[driver_id].nationality;
  span.textContent = drivers[driver_id].age;
  article.textContent = drivers[driver_id].name;
  div.appendChild(h2);
  div.appendChild(span);
  div.appendChild(article);
  return div;
 }

 myProfile = driverProfile(drivers);
 profile.appendChild(myProfile);
```

The program give error because your function is not of return type and you are assigning function to `myProfile` variable.

`appendChild` function takes html elements as Object but you had given function. Just change function to return type as shown in above code.

Answer (score 0):

driverProfile is not returning any node. At the end of this function you need to return the node you want to be appended.

Comment: can you give me some example?

Comment: when I am trying to return one value it works, but when i do `return {article, h2, span};` it throws the same error

Comment: Each item in that list is a node. But you are return a bunch of nodes which is not correct. You need to return only one.